# Related to the construction of $\Bbb C$ (generalisation)

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

To construct $\Bbb C$, we consider $\Bbb R^2$ endowed with the operations: $$\begin{align} (a,b) + (c,d) &:= (a+c, b+d) \\ (a,b) \cdot (c,d) &:= (ac - bd, ad+bc)\end{align} $$
then write $(0,1_{\Bbb R}) = i$, go on writing $(a,b)$ as $a+ib$, etc. Maybe the question is silly and has a trivial explanation, but nevertheless, I'll ask: Has anyone ever tried to repeat the procedure with $\Bbb C^2$, "nesting imaginary units"?
More specifically, I mean, define on $\Bbb C^2$ the operations: $$\begin{align} (z_1,z_2) + (w_1,w_2) &:= (z_1 + w_1, z_2+w_2) \\ (z_1,z_2) \cdot (w_1,w_2) &:= (z_1w_1 - z_2w_2, z_1w_2+z_2w_1)\end{align}$$
then write $(0,1_{\Bbb C}) = j$, where $j$ is another "imaginary unit" such that $j^2 = -1_{\Bbb C}$, write $(z_1,z_2) = z_1 + jz_2$ and so on? (I'm just using this subscript $\Bbb C$ for emphasis). It seems to me that we would get $i^2 = j^2$, but that wouldn't mean necessarily that $i = j$, would it? Also, would be this related in any way to the quaternions?

This, way, if we can make $\Bbb C^2$ a field, we could make any $\Bbb R^{2n}, n \in \Bbb Z$ a field, by repeating the process, no? I don't know if any problem would appear if I expanded everything in terms of the real and imaginary parts of every component. We would get some mixed terms $ij$ and $ji$. Surely I could adventure myself in the calculations, but if someone already thought of this, and it ended up being meaningless, I won't keep hitting my head on the wall. Thank you for the attention, and I hope I managed to get my idea through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're essentially adjoining a new square root of $-1$ to $\Bbb C$, namely $(0,1)$. In effect you are constructing the ring $\Bbb C[x]/(x^2+1)$ (where $x$ represents this new sqrt of $-1$). By the Chinese Remainder Theorem (the one used in abstract algebra), this is isomorphic to

$$\frac{\Bbb C[x]}{((x+i)(x-i))}\cong\frac{\Bbb C[x]}{(x+i)}\times\frac{\Bbb C[x]}{(x-i)}\cong\Bbb C\times\Bbb C .$$

This is a direct product of $\Bbb C$ with itself. It's certainly not a field; it has many zero divisors (nonzero things that multiply into zero: e.g. $(a,0)(0,b)=(0,0)$ in $\Bbb C\times\Bbb C$) and four idempotents (things that satisfiy $u^2=u$). If you adjoin yet another one, you get

$$\frac{(\Bbb C\times\Bbb C)[x]}{(x^2+1)}\cong\frac{\Bbb C[x]}{(x^2+1)}\times\frac{\Bbb C[x]}{(x^2+1)}\cong\Bbb C\times\Bbb C\times\Bbb C\times\Bbb C.$$

The first isomorphism is $(a,b)+(c,d)x+(x^2+1)\mapsto (a+cx+(x^2+1),b+dx+(x^2+1))$.

Notice this new ring again has many zero divisors, so it's not a field or a division ring (like the quaternions $\Bbb H$ are), and it's also commutative (unlike $\Bbb H$) and four-dimensional over $\Bbb C$ (as opposed to $\Bbb H$, which is four-dimensional over $\Bbb R$) hence eight-dimensional over $\Bbb R$.

[Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28real_division_algebras%29) states that the only real division algebras over $\Bbb R$ are $\Bbb R,\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb H$, so you will not be able to get any higher-dimensional ones no matter how clever your construction.

If you alter the $2$-tuple construction of $\Bbb C$ out of $\Bbb R$ with conjugation, you get the [Cayley-Dickson construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction): if you apply this construction to $\Bbb C$, you get $\Bbb H$ (no longer commutative), and if you apply it to $\Bbb H$ you get the octonions $\Bbb O$ (no longer associative), and then the sedenions (no longer "alternative") and so on.  Another generalization of $\Bbb R,\Bbb C,\Bbb H$ are [Clifford algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra).

Comment: Great answer. Thank you very much. I've got a lot to read about, now. +1

Answer (score 1):

Close. To get the complexes, use real matrices
$$ 
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  a  &  b  \\
   -b   &  a  
\end{array} 
  \right)  .
  $$

To get the quaternions, use complex matrices
$$ 
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  \alpha  &  \beta  \\
   -\bar{\beta}   &  \bar{\alpha}  
\end{array} 
  \right)  .
  $$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Hamilton and many others considered trying to do something of the sort; as it turns out we can't create an algebra structure in three dimensions, but we can do this in four. You can read about Hamilton's discovery of it [here](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Hamilton/Letters/BroomeBridge.html). This gives what are called quaternions: we have $i,j,k$ so that $i^2=j^2=k^2$; this gives $ij=k$ among other identities. However we lose commutativity: $ij=-ji$, for example, so this is no longer a field. They are, however, a division algebra, and an example of a skew field due to anticommutativity.

In eight dimensions there is a further construction of the octonions but we further lose associativity. We cannot do this in higher dimensions.

Comment: I had saw something like this, about the dimensions once, some time ago, but I hadn't thought it would be related to what I asked, right now. I'll read about it, thank you!